# getDerivedStateFromProps() vs componentDidUpdate()

Tags: react-native, getderivedstatefromprops

I am using `componentWillReceiveProps` in many places in my application. Now, I have to replace them with either `getDerivedStateFromProps()` or `componentDidUpdate()`. First I thought of using `getDerivedStateFromProps` as it s alternative of `componentWillReceiveProps` as suggested `react-native` docs. But some people are highly recommending not to use this method, Instead suggesting to use `componentDidUpdate`. But for my requirement all new props must be set with the `state` before render. `getDerivedStateFromProps` is the best place to do so.

Hence, which one to use between `getDerivedStateFromProps` and `componentDidUpdate`?

Comment: as a recommendation, you may wish to consider using hooks and functional components unless your components/application is heavily using class components already

Answer (score 0):

From the React docs

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

> `getDerivedStateFromProps` is invoked right before calling the render method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.

> Deriving state leads to verbose code and makes your components
> difficult to think about.
>
> Make sure you’re familiar with simpler alternatives:
>
> - If you need to **perform a side effect** (for example, data fetching or an animation) in response to a change in props, use `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle instead.
> - If you want to **re-compute some data only when a prop changes**, use a memoization helper instead.
> - If you want to **“reset” some state when a prop changes**, consider either making a component fully controlled or fully uncontrolled with a key instead.